# Flutter Impeller in android Emulator

Tags: flutter

Whenever I activate empeller in my emulator. the frames break like this.
it is working fine with Skia.
is the problem with impeller or do I need to add some extra configurations ?
#flutter #impeller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGFJO.jpg)

is the problem with impeller or do I need to add some extra configurations ?